# How to rout to child routes in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm just getting into Angular, so maybe this is a trivial problem.
I'm having trouble navigating to routes with `[routerLink]`

this is my hierarchy

```
/
-- /header
-- /home
-- /item1
---- /dashboard
---- /sub1
---- /sub2
-- /item2
---- /dashboard
---- /sub1
---- /sub2
...
```

in the `"/"` directory I am searching for an USB device and as soon as my app found it, the app redirects to `"/home"`

Inside my home component I have a variable number of items. Each of these items has the same subdirectories: `"item2/dashboard", "item2/sub1",...` (dashboard, etc. looks different for each item and is a unique component, but the routing structure is the same for every item)

My header component is a bootstrap navbar and with

`[hidden]="!(this.router.url !== '/' && this.router.url !== '/home')"`

new nav-items (dashboard, sub1, sub2, ...) are displayed when I'm not in the `"/"` or `"/home"` route. This way the header is expanded dynamically as soon as I'm in an item-component.
The navbar looks like this:

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Navigating from Home to my Items works like a charm. When entering an Item, it automatically redirects to `"Item/dashboard"`. I can also access every component, when I enter the url manually.

Now to my problem:

When I'm in Item1/dashboard and want to go to Item1/sub1 with the navbar, I want to do this with a relative path (because every Item is set up the same way) but I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'sub1'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'sub1'
```

Code of navitem:

```
<li class="nav-item active" [hidden]="!(this.router.url !== '/' && this.router.url !== '/home')">
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['../sub1']">
        sub1
    </a>
</li>
```

My Routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: LoadingComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
 { path: 'item1', component: Item1Component, children: ITEM1_ROUTES },
 { path: 'item2', component: Item2Component, children: ITEM2_ROUTES },
 ...
];
```

my childrouting:

```
export const ITEM1_ROUTES: Routes = [
 { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'dashboard', component: Item1DashboardComponent },
 { path: 'sub1', component: Item1Sub1Component },
 { path: 'sub2', component: Item1Sub2Component },
 { path: 'sub3', component: Item1Sub3Component },
 { path: 'sub4', component: Item1Sub4Component }
];
```

Why can't I access the child route relatively?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to navigate relatively, you need to supply to which route the new route is relative.

I don't think you can achieve that in the template. For a way to do this programmatically in your TS class, see https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#relativeTo

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't solve this yet, this is how should look child routes in your Angular application:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'product-list', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'product-list', component: ProductList 
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'overview', component: Overview },
      { path: 'specs', component: Specs }
    ]
  }
];
```

and if you want to navigate to any child routes you can do this

```
//This is wrong url and angular doesn't know where to navigate
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['../sub1']">
        sub1
</a>

// This is the right way to navigate
// parent-route/child-route
product-list
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/product-list/overview']">
        Product List overview
</a>
```

Also pay attention if you don't put '/' in front of your url you will navigate relatively where are you at this moment

For example now you are on `/feed` page and if you'll navigate like this without `/` this will go to `/feed/product-list/overview` and you'll get an error because you don't have any routes like this one, so make sure to star `routerLinnk` with `/` `[routerLink]="/product-list/overview"`

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['product-list/overview']">
        Product List overview
</a>
```

You can use `routerLink` whithout `/` at the beginning when you have to navigate from `/product` to specific product => `[routerLink]="[product/ , productId]"` so you'll navigate from current location to specific product